# xmlhttp is undefined. Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to javascript and especially to ajax..And just trying to figure it out..

i wrote this code from one tutorial and can't find what i did wrong. [Here you can see it live](http://private-db.net16.net/test/index.html)

The error i am getting from Firebug: "TypeError: xmlhttp is undefined
[Break On This Error]

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){"

my code is

```
// JavaScript Document

var xmlhttp;
var url;

function ajaxFunction(){

if  (window.ActiveXObject){//if the window is InternetExplorer

    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// if Window is Firefox etc..

        xmmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();

        }else{

            alert ("Get a New Browser")

            }

}//end of ajaxFunction()


function getInfo(){

    ajaxFunction();

    var entryInfo= document.getElementById("entry").value;

            function stateChanged(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    }//if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)

                }//end of function stateChanged()


url = "info.php?user="+entryInfo;
xmlhttp.onreadystateshange=stateChanged();
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);


    }// end of function getInfo
```

Comment: Your `onreadystatechange` property should be a reference to the function without `()`, not the function call with `()`  as in `xmlhttp.onreadystateshange = stateChanged;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
   xmmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
     ^
```

Change to

```
 xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Also as Michael pointed out, you have parenthesis when assigning your onreadystatechange function:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystateshange=stateChanged();
                                       ^ remove the ()
```

If you don't remove the parenthesis, the `stateChange()` function will be called, and the return value will be given to `xmlhttp.onreadystateshange` which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistype in property name: 
`xmlhttp.onreadystateshange=stateChanged;`

It has to be `'onreadystatechange'`.