# "Uncaught RefereceError: txtfile is not defined"

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am getting a bit tired of this.

I have no idea why it keeps telling me the file is not defined, given that both the declaration and the usage of it, is within the same scope.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var inputarea = document.inputtext;
            txtFile.open("GET", "start.txt", true);
            txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
                if(txtFile.readyState === 4) {
                    // Makes sure it's found the file.
                    if(txtFile.status === 200) {
                        allText = txtFile.responseText;
                        // Will separate each line into an array
                        lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
                        for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                            var s = lines[i];
                            if(s.indexOf("nextpage") > -1) {
                                // Line is there

                            } else {
                                // Line is not there
                                inputarea.value += s;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            txtfile.send();
        </script>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="inputtext" rows="4" cols="20" readonly="readonly">

        </textarea>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Problem have been solved, though I get another error now:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (00:27:29:739 | error, javascript)
    at txtFile.onreadystatechange (public_html/index.html:29:42)`

Comment: What line is that error on?

Comment: I think this might help [xmlhttp-is-undefined-javascript-ajax][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585807/xmlhttp-is-undefined-javascript-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your spelling `txtfile.send()` should be `txtFile.send()`, note the capitalisation of the `f`

**Update for second error**

The error is because `document.inputtext` is undefined, I assume its meant to be an html element input box. If this is correct it might be worth giving the input an `id` of `inputtext` then calling it with `var inputarea = document.getElementById('inputtext')`. Although if you are going to do this, it would be worth putting the whole script in a `window.onload` callback so the input is present on the page when the script runs.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thank you. But now I get a new error. I will update the OP.

Comment: Which do you reckon would be the easiest..? I am fairly new to all this but have experience in other languages (C# and Java)

Comment: I gave it an ID as you said, and then moved the entire thing into the body instead. Making that callback thing would probably be smart and all, but I am really new to this so I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: To put it in a window onload callback I'd leave it in the head, but wrap the code in window.onload = function(){ <Your code here> }. That way the element should be present when the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to define `txtFile.onreadystatechange` before you call `txtFile.open`. Not sure if that is your problem though.

Comment: Youre "supposed" to assign it before .send(), not .open(), but I've found that isn't actually important

Comment: I have had the same experience. I have seen people say both. I've always declared event handlers before open just to be safe but like you, I've never noticed a difference.

Comment: Funny thing is, jQuery sets `onreadystatechange` **after** calling `.send()` even. I was baffled when I saw that in the source code